# Disabling my fixed background image on mobile and tablets

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, tablet

I'm using a fixed background on my website and it looks great on desktops. Unfortunately, it didn't show up correctly on my mobile and tablet, so I've used the following code to disable it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
body {
    background-image: none !important;
}
}
```

However, the issue I have now is dealing with tablets that are larger. A friend I know has a tablet larger than 1280px, but I don't want to go much over that max-width on my media query because then my fixed background won't be seen on desktops either. Is there any way at all to do media queries and disable elements like this for mobile/tablet specifically, rather than screen sizes, so this isn't an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue many times, the only css solution I've found that seems to work is using the pointer CSS media query.

> The pointer CSS media feature tests whether the user has a pointing device (such as a mouse), and if so, how accurate the primary pointing device is.

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer)

The following code will target touch devices:

```
// Remove background-attachment fixed on touch devices
@media (pointer: coarse) {
  background-attachment: initial;
}
```